# User design for many items over a time frame

Tags: info-visualisation, timeline

I would like to represent a sequence of user events (for ex. login events) under a graph. This would typically hold zero to infinite entries.

To represent users I intend to use small icons of, say, roughly 64x64. But how do I represent them with good UX over a timeline ? If for example I simply draw them over a line representing time, there may be blanks and overlaps. If i represent them in fixed space sequence, I loose the information of how much time elapses between events and may need to re-include that anyhow. I'm thinking I could make use of more available screen space.

[image: Mockups describing the envisionated solutions]

Should I keep any of these two designs ? Can they be improved ? Can a completely different fit ? I'm open to all and any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any mock-ups for what you're trying to do? It would be easier to understand the problem

Comment: @Aline added a quick paint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

[image]

Adding a new dimension to your chart.

Comment: I have this moment where I feel dumb not having thought of it myself. Many thanks for this proposition !

Comment: No problem! :D .